# How do I start my webApp once I have the Apache Tomcat7 Server running

Tags: javascript, apache, google-chrome, tomcat, server

I am trying to host my webapp. I started with a python simpleserver, but had errors, and so with chrome and other browsers I wasn't able to send my files like a csv.

The error is XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:... Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

And Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load .

So I tried Apache Tomcat 7 as a server, however after starting Apache7 I am confused as to how I view my webapp. I tried putting my webapp into the apache bin and calling it with localhost:8080/dataAnalyticsProject/page.html but that produces a 404 error.

My files are located in C:\Users\apt\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.63-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\webapps\dataAnalyticsProject. How do I start up this server so that I can view my webapp?

Thanks

Comment: This question is super-confusing because you are doing a whole bunch of things. Can you ask one thing at a time?

Comment: Try putting your web application in the `webapps` directory instead of in the `bin` directory and that ought to solve the deployment problem with Tomcat.